# Expected Value for uniform random permutations using random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, expected-value

> **Question:** Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer. You are given n beer bottles $B_1, B_2,...B_n$ and one cider bottle $C$. Consider a uniformly random permutation of these $n + 1$ bottles. The positions in this permutation are numbered as $1, 2, 3,...,n + 1$.
>
> Define the random variable X to be:
>
> X= the position of the leftmost beer bottle.
>
> What is the expected value E(X) of the random variable X?

**Answer:** $\frac{(n+2)}{(n+1)}$

**Attempt:**

Total ways to arrange bottles: (n+1)! ways

The position of the leftmost beer: 1 way

E(X) = $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i*Pr(X = position, of, the, leftmost, beer)$$

E(X) = $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} = 1*\frac{{n+1 \choose 1}*1}{(n+1)!} $$

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} $$

Can't seem to simplify it to get the correct answer.

Comment: Please be extremely careful in writing summations. Remember that the expectation of a random variable $X$ is summing all products of the form $i \cdot \mathrm{Pr}(X = i).$ Adjust this in edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left most beer bottle can be on position 1 or 2. If it is on position 1 then cider bootle can be on any position between 2 and n+1, so we have $n$ possibilities for cider bootle among all $n+1$ positions. Else if cider bottle is on position 1 and leftmost bottle is on position 2. So we have: $$E(X) = 1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2) $$
  $$ = {n\over n+1}+2{1\over n+1}$$

Comment: why are you basing it off the cider bottle's probability of positioning?

Comment: All the permutations depend only on the cider bottle. It uniqely determine each permuatiton.